# Variance of the predicted temperature

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am predicting the electrical load and I also use the **predicted temperature** as one of the input feature. For example, I want to predict the electrical for tomorrow. I use the predicted temperature for tomorrow as an input feature.

Since in the real application the prediceted temperature will have an error, I want to add a noise to the temperature. However, I dont know how much noise I should add to the temperature. Do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish by adding this noise?

Comment: Since the predicted value for temperature is not exactly same as the actual value, and electric load has a powerful correlation with temperature. If I add noise to temperature, probably my model will be more robust.

Comment: It's hard to see how injecting noise into this analysis could improve it.